# complex numbers modulus problems

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|z_1+z_2|^2=|z_1-z_2|^2$ where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are non zero complex numbers, then which one is correct

(a) Re$\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=0$

(b) Im $\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=0$

(c) $Re(z_1+z_2)=0$

Can we take $z_1 = a+bi$ and $z_2 = x+iy$

Now $|z_1+z_2|^2 = |(a+x)+i(b+y)|^2 = (a+x)^2+(b+y)^2 $.......(i)

Also $|z_1-z_2|^2 = |(a-x)+i(b-y)|^2 = (a-x)^2+(b-y)^2..$.....(ii)

Since (i) = (ii)

After solving these two equation i get : $4ax +4by=0$ .....(iii)

What to do next ? could you please guide....

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\frac{a+ib}{x+iy}=\frac{(a+ib)(x-iy)}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{ax+by+i(bx-ay)}{x^2+y^2}$$
so you can conclude according to your work that $\Re(\frac{z_1} {z_2})=0$

Answer (score 0):

Find $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ then you will be able to find the correct solution.